# How to call Vue's method from jquery

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I use jquery(signalR) in vue's project

And I want to call components vue's method in jquery function

But i have no idea how to do this

this is my vue's method

```
methods: {
　clearMessage () {
  　this.message = ''
},
```

this is my jquery

```
$(function() {
    //call clearMessage here
});
```

Comment: I would recommend that you throw jQuery out of your project. Vue works ina whole other way than jQuery.
What manipulations are you trying to do with jQuery in this case? Instead of manipulating the dom, you can simply use a nice Vue binding.

Comment: In addition to what @sandrooco mentioned, it is not easily possible to access Vue methods from jQuery. You would need to pass a reference to that method somehow (with a lifecycle hook of Vue) to the scope of jQuery (probably via global scope) which is just not what you should do. A Vue component might also exist multiple times which must be considered... If you absolutely require jQuery in your Vue project, go the other way around and instantiate the jQuery part in a lifecycle hook of Vue (and revert the changes in the unmount hook).